# Has China not published an official number of Covid-19 tests performed in its territory?

Tags: china, covid-19, statistics

Taiwan’s vice president Chen Chien-jen claimed in a [May 8 interview with France24](https://youtu.be/G1potR0eXA4?t=197) (around 3:40) that they cannot find the official number of Covid-19 tests performed in China... the implication being obviously that such [official] numbers aren't easily available or even published by China.

(Note that he is not talking about the number of cases reported but rather the number of tests performed; that number is also important in a number of ways e.g. [relative to the number of cases found](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23511/is-there-a-graph-over-time-of-covid-19-test-positivity-rate-in-the-us).)

So, is that true basically, has China not officially (and conspicuously) published the number of Covid-19 tests it has performed?

Comment: One needs to keep in mind that reports of US testing are, um, incredible:  [Public labs have done 819 thousand tests](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/cases-updates/testing-in-us.html).  [Trump says US will pass 10 million coronavirus tests this week](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2020/05/11/coronavirus-trump-says-us-pass-10-million-tests-states-get-11-billion/3111814001/).

Comment: @DanielRHicks - I don't think 10 million tests is that incredible.  Even assuming that every test was on a different person (and given that the White House staff has been [repeatedly tested](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/05/12/us/coronavirus-testing-white-house.html), that distribution seems unlikely), that's still a 3% testing rate - which is [definitely not enough](https://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2020/04/22/840526338/is-the-u-s-testing-enough-for-covid-19-as-debate-rages-on-heres-how-to-know).

Comment: @jdunlop - Think about it -- "in-credible".

Comment: @DanielRHicks I know, I was treating the word by its original definition.  But I think 10 million tests is a credible figure.  Whether those tests are good, or well-distributed, or consistently applied are obviously confounding factors, but I'd view "we've administered ten million tests" as a credible assertion at this point.

Comment: @jdunlop - 10 million tests would be good.  But there's no way that number have been done in the US.  If you believe Trump's claim that that many tests have been done I have some beachfront property in the Mohave Desert to sell you.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - I don't think it's that unreasonable.  Since mid-April, the average tests-per-day has been more than two hundred thousand.  If the total throughout the pandemic isn't at ten million, it's probably close.  The problem is that the _low_ bound of "how many should be done" is in the range of a million tests _per day_, which makes the ten million claim by Trump like someone saying "I won the marathon!" having run two blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OurWorldInData](https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus-testing) includes China on a long list of countries for which it could not find official data for testing performed. They note as of 05 May 2020:

> we are not aware of any figures relating to the whole of China. There is some data relating to parts of China, for instance press releases concerning testing in Guangdong province.